# Limit involving $\pi$ and the Fibonacci sequence.

Tags: limits, logarithms, gcd-and-lcm, fibonacci-numbers, pi

In [this blog](https://curiosamathematica.tumblr.com/post/176396903518/from-fibonacci-to-%CF%80) I found a curious limit that involves the Fibonnaci sequence and the number
$ \pi$.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{x}log F_i}{log (lcm \left \{ F_i \right \}_{i=0}^{x })}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

In the case of the limit is correct,
Could anyone give me some pointers about the demo?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.